# Firebase cloud functions - write to database on create user

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to write to database, every time a new user is registered. This is my code:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    exports.newUserToDatabaseTest = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    var current = new Date().toString();
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({
        email: user.email,
        creationDate: current
        })
  });
```

It deploys correctly, but nothing is happening after a new user registers in my React Native app.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When writing Firebase Cloud Functions always take care that you need to "tell" the function to wait if you run async code. Otherwise it will stop before your code executes. For that we return your `set` to the database.

Also the `auth` trigger gives you the `user` so you can use that to get the user uid.

The `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` will not work in cloud functions.

Try changing your code to something like this:

```js
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');

  const admin = require('firebase-admin');
  admin.initializeApp();

    exports.newUserToDatabaseTest = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    var current = new Date().toString();
    return admin.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
        email: user.email,
        creationDate: current
        })
  });
```

Comment: You need to use the Admin SDK in a Cloud Function. Initialize an admin app instance from which RTDB changes can be made. (`const admin = require('firebase-admin'); admin.initializeApp();`) and then do `admin.database().ref('...')...`